# 2Cannot press return to submit form and run JS action

Tags: php, javascript, html

This has got to be easier than I'm making it.  I ahve a form that has an onclick action, it runs js that submits the form value to another page.  How do I allow users to press return to perform the same action?  I've tried some onkeypress stuff, but nothing has worked.  Below is the form, and the js being run.

Thanks!

**updated code to reflect more of what I am trying to do..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getQueryValue(name) {
                var match = (new RegExp('[?&;]' + name + '=([^&;#]*)')).exec(document.URL);
                return match ? unescape(match[1]) : null;
        }
        var ext = "&ext="+getQueryValue('ext');
        </script>
        <script src="prototype.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkSubmit(e)
        {
           if(e && e.keyCode == 13) // if key is enter
           {
              doSubmit(); // call your submit function
           }
        }
        </script>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="dialNumber_form">
                <form id="dialer" style="margin-bottom:0;">
                        <input id="numberBox" name="outnumber" onKeyUp="checkSubmit(event)" type="text">
                        <input id="submitButton" onsubmit="dosubmit()" type="button"/>
                </form>
                <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="success">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function dosubmit( ) {
                        var par = $('dialer').serialize();
                        var url = par + ext;
                        new Ajax.Updater('success', 'dial.php', { method: 'post' , parameters: url , evalScripts: true } );
                        $('dialer').reset();
                }
        </script>
</body>
```

dial.php is taking the number you enter in the field, checking that it's valid, and sending it to our PBX to be dialed.  This works, assuming you click the submit button.  If you press return (even with the updated code, as recommended below), the page refreshes, and the contents of the outnumber box are posted as GET URL variable, rather than being sent to the dosubmit action.  When the form works, you see it stay as it was originally built (`dialout.htm?ext={extension number}`)

Thanks for all the responses.  Let me try some of your suggestions, and I'll get back to you.

Not sure I'm clear in what I need to accomplish.  This entire thing is being run in an iframe that is passed URL variables.  I have no control over that piece, so I need to work with what I've got.  When a user opens it, the URL would look something like `.../dialout.htm?ext=1234`.  The extension is used, along with the number entered into the `outnumber` box, to place a call (system dials extension first, then outnumber).  They should be passed to dial.php for processing, and if everything is good, a success response is sent back with the results (and the call is made).  This works great if the dial button is clicked.  The page does not refresh, and after a short delay, the success box pops up and a call is placed.  If enter is pressed, the form refreshes, and the URL changes to `.../dialout.htm?outnumber=<number>`.  I want enter to do what clicking the dial button does.  Nothing i've tried here really works for that (unless I'm just really slow..).  Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you'll need to make the type attribute on the button 'submit' (type="submit"). That should make it fire off on return as if it was clicked, assuming the form it is contained in was in focus.

Comment: the `keyPress` listener should be on the text field not on the submit button ...

Comment: have you tried using the onsubmit event and a submit button? This tends to make things easier as well as providing a fallback

Comment: I have tried this, and it doesn't work as I expect it to.  The goal is to submit the form without refreshing, and return something in the success <div>.  Changing to `type=submit` causes the page to refresh, the contents of the textbox are sent to the URL as a variable.  I will update the code with the entire page, so you have context.

Comment: @lorsungcu - You are getting a double submit, once from AJAX and once from the normal form submit process. The refresh you see is from the normal submit. If you return `false` from the submit handler (as I say in my answer) you will prevent the "normal" submit and no refresh will happen.

Comment: submit is not an event for a button, it's an event for a form.

Comment: If you want a form to submit when you hit a button either include a <input type="submit"> or attach an event that submits the form to click.

Comment: I very often `tab` to the submit button and press `space` to "click" the button. `onclick` handlers miss that, as do `if (key==13)` tests, which is why I stick with `onsubmit` handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your submit button `<input type="submit" id="submitButton" etc>` then attach an `onsubmit` handler. jQuery:

```
$("#dialer").submit(function() {
    var result = doMyStuff();
    if (result > 10) {
        return false; // prevent the submit
    }
    else {
        return true; // allow the submit to happen
    }
});
```

See the [jQuery .submit() docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Returning `false` prevents the submit from occurring, true allows it. (I normally wouldn't put a "return false else return true" (return (result<=10);) but wanted to make the true/false sumbit control explicit)

When using AJAX to do the submit you'd want to return `false` so the normal submit is suppressed.

---

#### Update:

Returning `false` to stop default event processing is, these days, mostly deprecated. Using `preventDefault()` is generally preferred.  This would change my example to be:

```
$("#dialer").submit(function(event) {
    var result = doMyStuff();
    if (result > 10) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent the form submit
    }
});
```

Comment: Reason for the drive-by downvote? Help me improve my answers if you think there's something wrong.

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted, but I do notice you missed a double quote in your selector: `$("submitButton")`

Comment: Submit is not an event for a button. It's an event for a form. Your example doesn't work.

Comment: @peterp - Duh! Thanks for pointing that out, I certainly know better as I use this technique often.

Answer (score 0):

The keyDown / keyUp listener should be on the input not the submit button

```
<input id="numberBox" name="outnumber" onKeyUp="checkSubmit(event)" type="text">

function checkSubmit(e)
{
   if(e && e.keyCode == 13) // if key is enter
   {
      doSubmit(); // call your submit function
   }
}
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/sVnMy/

This will listen to key presses on the input field and when the enter key is pressed it will submit the form

Comment: I've added this, exactly as you have it, and when I press enter, the URL just changes to ".../dialout.htm?outnumber={contents of text box}".  I am expecting that dosubmit() will submit the form without refreshing the window, and return with stuff in the success <div>.  any ideas?